# in javascript, having problems maintaining scope in function wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, scope

have outer / inner functions repeated multiple times.  the outer function is always the same except for the inner function call, eg, `e.target.ffunc1()`.

```
util.func1 = function( e, successFunc, failureFunc ) {
  e.target.ffunc1( function( err ) {
    if( !err && successFunc )       successFunc();
    else if( err && failureFunc )   failureFunc();
    else if( err )                  nonblockAlert( err );
  } );
}
HTMLInputElement.prototype.ffunc1 = function( nextFunc ) {  ... }

util.func2 = func...
HTMLInputElement.prototype.ffunc2 = func...

...
```

trying to write a sugar wrapper to use when defining these outer functions.

have tried the obvious:

```
util.wrapper = function( e, callFunc, successFunc, failureFunc ) {
        callFunc( function( err ) {
                if( !err && successFunc )       successFunc();
                else if( err && failureFunc )   failureFunc();
                else if( err )                  nonblockAlert( err );
        } );
}
util.func1 = function( e, successFunc, failureFunc ) {
  util.wrapper( e. e.target.ffunc1, successFunc, failureFunc );
}
```

but this fails because `this` in `ffunc1` is not `e.target`, but rather the event to which `func1` was responding.  In retrospect, this makes perfect sense.

At a loss on how to write the wrapper function that preserves the scope (?) of `e.target.ffunc1` call, that is, when `ffunc1` is executed, `this` is `e.target` from the outer `func1` function.

(disclaimer: I acknowledge that many people for very good reasons do not overload dom elements, and I respect that position.  however, )

---

the solution, as everyone (but me) seems to know, was `call`:

```
util.wrapperDB = function( e, callFunc, successFunc, failureFunc ) {
        callFunc.call( e.target, function( err ) {
                if( !err && successFunc )       successFunc();
                else if( err && failureFunc )   failureFunc();
                else if( err )                  nonblockAlert( err );
        } );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `call()` method on the function object? I.e.

```
func.call( [this argument], arg1, arg2, ...);
```

In your code:

```
callFunc.call( e.target, function( err ) {
            if( !err && successFunc )       successFunc();
            else if( err && failureFunc )   failureFunc();
            else if( err )                  nonblockAlert( err );
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may help is JavaScript's `call` method which lets you pass in what you want `this` to be inside the called function. Example: `e.target.ffunc1.call(e.target)`.

<strike>I'll update with more details when I get to work.</strike>

**UPDATE:** Looks like Martin beat me to it. Glad you got it working!